# WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: hadoop

`alpesh@alpesh-Inspiron-3647:~/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin$ hadoop fs -ls
16/07/05 13:59:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

It is also showing me the the output as below

`hadoop check native -a
16/07/05 14:00:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false 
16/07/05 14:00:42 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1`

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 12):

Library you are using is compiled for 32 bit and you are using 64 bit version. so open your .bashrc file where configuration for hadoop exists. Go to this line

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

and replace it with

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh , I  had did this but still it show me  following error. after giving command like hadoop fs -ls
16/07/05 14:41:24 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory

Comment: ok, after editing this file make sure to run this command (source .bashrc) and then check

Comment: Yes , now this native msg is solved  , Please help me to run hadoop command . It is show error as follows hadoop fs -mkdir sam
mkdir: `sam': No such file or directory

Comment: Run it like this 
hadoop fs -mkdir /sam

It is just like our linux filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh please tell me how to create txt file into hadoop

Comment: Dear Rakesh , when I am tring to copy file from local to hdfs it showing me  File /home/kalpesh/kalpesh.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

Comment: before starting things did you formatted your name node?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545524/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation

Comment: HADOOP_OPTS wasnt at bashrc. Instead at /etc/hadoop/hadoop_env.sh and upon addition of the above line it still gave the same error. Running on Fedora 25 64bit Apache Spark2.1 hadoop 2.7

Comment: what is the beat way for mac El capiton ? any thoughts about that

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this error:

Suppose Jar file is at `/home/cloudera/test.jar` and class file is at `/home/cloudera/workspace/MapReduce/bin/mapreduce/WordCount`, where `mapreduce` is the package name.

Input file `mytext.txt` is at `/user/process/mytext.txt` and output file location is `/user/out`.

We should run this `mapreduce` program in following way:

```
$hadoop jar /home/cloudera/bigdata/text.jar mapreduce.WordCount /user/process /user/out
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties in bash profile of Hadoop user, the issue will be solved

> export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
>
> export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR"

Answer (score -2):

It's just a warning, because it can not find the correct .jar. Either by compiling it or because it does not exist.

If I were you, I would simply omit it

To do that add in the corresponding configuration file

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=ERROR
```