# Error on hadoop as a distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I tried to use hadoop as a distributed mode, and I did setup but an error has occurred.
I describe setup procedure below:

①Server constitution

Master server's hostname is master, and slave servers' names are node1 and node2.
All server's OS is CentOS7.
master's ip address is 131.113.101.103, slaves' ip address are 131.113.101.101 and 131.113.101.102.

②setting on each server

fixed /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname. I describe only master server.
○/etc/hostname

```
master
```

○/etc/hosts

```
131.113.101.101   node1
131.113.101.102   node2
131.113.101.103   master
```

Installed packages

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install openssh-clients rsync wget java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel sshpass
```

Get hadoop

```
wget http://ftp.riken.jp/net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.1/hadoop-2.8.1.tar.gz
tar xf hadoop-2.8.1.tar.gz
```

Fixed .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
export HADOOP_HOME=~/hadoop-2.8.1
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I checked `hadoop version` and it works.

③Setting on Master server

configurations of ssh without pass phrase

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and send to node1 and node2, and changed name to authorized_keys. Also I accessed from master to node1 and node2 to check, I could access without pass phrase.

○/etc/hadoop/slaves

```
node1
node2
```

○/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://131.113.101.103:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hadoop-username/</value>
</property>
```

○/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
  <value>131.113.101.103:50090</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data</value>
</property>
```

○/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

○/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>
```

I send these config files to node1 and node2.

④start hadoop

format HDFS

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

start daemon

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start historyserver
```

then I use `jps` command to check each server's processes.

Master server is

```
NameNode
Jps
ResourceManager
SecondaryNameNode
JobHistoryServer
```

node servers are

```
DataNode
Jps
NodeManager
```

Then I tried to use this command

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.1.jar pi 10 10000
```

But these error codes has returned

```
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 10000
17/10/25 03:00:16 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/username/QuasiMonteCarlo_1508868015200_1006439027/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:788)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2455)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:335)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:658)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/username/QuasiMonteCarlo_1508868015200_1006439027/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:788)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2455)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:335)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:658)
```

I searched for the solution but there are no achievements.

----added----

the result of

```
 bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

is

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
```

It seems there are no active datanodes…

But on node1 and node2, it seems datanode process from an aspect of a jps result.

and checked  `/home/username/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-username-datanode-node1.out` and `home/username/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-username-datanode-node2.out`

Result is below:

○node1

```
ulimit -a for user username
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256944
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

○node2

```
ulimit -a for user username
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256944
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I also checked `sudo netstat -ntlp` on master server, and the result and the `jps` result are below:

○jps result

```
17252 JobHistoryServer
16950 ResourceManager
17418 Jps
16508 NameNode
16701 SecondaryNameNode
```

○sudo netstat -ntlp result

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 131.113.101.103:50090   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16701/java                 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19888           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17252/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17252/java                
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16508/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17252/java          
tcp        0      0 131.113.101.103:9000    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16508/java         
tcp6       0      0 131.113.101.103:8088    :::*                    LISTEN      16950/java                  
tcp6       0      0 131.113.101.103:8030    :::*                    LISTEN      16950/java          
tcp6       0      0 131.113.101.103:8031    :::*                    LISTEN      16950/java          
tcp6       0      0 131.113.101.103:8032    :::*                    LISTEN      16950/java          
tcp6       0      0 131.113.101.103:8033    :::*                    LISTEN      16950/java
```

On node2 result is below:

○jps result

```
12228 NodeManager
12045 DataNode
12493 Jps
```

○sudo netstat -ntlp result

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33742         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12045/java         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12045/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12045/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12045/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      12228/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::13562                :::*                    LISTEN      12228/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      12228/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::42633                :::*                    LISTEN      12228/java
```

are there any wrong points?

I thought it strange that on node2 there are no local address "131.113.101.102".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stack trace shows that the datanodes are not running. Check for data node startup logs for more info. Apart from this you can see if your problem is similar to what is [here](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545524/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation). Also try running the below command
from name node. Although I am running hadoop on standalone - it should show similar info for you indicating the number of live datanodes.

```
 bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

It should give you info about the live nodes

```
Configured Capacity: 240611487744 (224.09 GB)
Present Capacity: 79048312831 (73.62 GB)
DFS Remaining: 79040917504 (73.61 GB)
DFS Used: 7395327 (7.05 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
Under replicated blocks: 36
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (127.0.0.1)
Hostname: HSNMM-Shailendra.com
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 240611487744 (224.09 GB)
DFS Used: 7395327 (7.05 MB)
Non DFS Used: 161563174913 (150.47 GB)
DFS Remaining: 79040917504 (73.61 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 32.85%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Oct 24 23:39:47 IST 2017
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I checked datanodes and it seems not active.
But, I don't know how to be active the datanodes.

Comment: On startup the datanode tries connecting to namenode. Is this info present in your data node logs ?

Comment: Yes. 
The message which is returned when I ran "sbin/start-dfs.sh" is "node1: starting datanode, logging to /home/username/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-username-datanode-node1.out". So I thought the datanode log is above file. Is it wrong?

Comment: When I used -put command same error has occurred.
I thought datanodes are active but namenode can't  access datanode, is it wrong?

Comment: I forgot to open the ports, so I opened ports which shows in "sudo netstat -ntlp result". Then the process slightly proceeded. But  new error has occurred. The error message is "no route to host", and consequently the message  "Retrying connect to server: 131.113.101.102:"port_num""  was returned. I opened the "port_num" but then the message "Retrying connect to server: 131.113.101.102:"another_port_num"" was returned. I thought the "port_num" is not constant value, so should I open which port to access slave nodes?

Comment: There are new processes "MRAppMaster" and "YarnChild", and the "port_num" and "another_port_num" is a port for these processes.
This error has occurred after the message "mapreduce.Jop: Running Job".

Comment: I temporally stopped firewalld and try to run hadoop. It works well.