# Window ID resets to 0 after it reaches 59 in DTconsole

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-apex

I am currently working on apache apex. My application gets reset after window ID 59 is reached and starts again from 0. I get an error which says that there is only 1 datanode running and no nodes are excluded in this operation

Comment: All content of errors would be helpful in here. Add that by edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried steps given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545524/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your application might be failing due to failure during checkpoint as default checkpoint window is 60

But it will be great if you update your question with any exception from logs.