# Hadoop error: _COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1)

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to execute following command in ubuntu18 where hdfs is installed. Kindly help.

```
hadoop fs -put /home/root-sai/Downloads/sample.txt /RBI
```

Error:

```
put: File /RBI/sample.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545524/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation

Comment: finally got a solution which is very simple.    1)stop-dfs.sh  2)delete temporary files from datanode 3)Hadoop namenode -format 4)start-dfs.sh and continue with the command that giving error...It works like wonder.