# Hadoop + Spark: There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am currently experimenting with Apache Spark. Everything seems to be working fine in that all the various components are up and running (i.e. HDFS, Spark, Yarn, etc). There do not appear to be any errors during the startup of any of these. I am running this in a Vagrant VM and Spark/HDFS/Yarn are dockerized.

**tl;dr**: Submitting an job via Yarn results in `There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation`.

Submitting my application with: `$ spark-submit --master yarn --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 /Users/foobar/Downloads/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar 10`

Which results in the following:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Pi
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: foobar
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: foobar
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(foobar); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(foobar); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 52142.
20/05/03 17:45:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/1x/h0q3vtw17ddbys9bjcf41mtr0000gn/T/blockmgr-1a34b35e-d5c2-4c11-a637-364f86818b1a
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 93.3 MB
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://foobars-mbp.box:4040
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/foobar/Downloads/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar at spark://foobars-mbp.box:52142/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar with timestamp 1588545927208
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
20/05/03 17:45:27 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
20/05/03 17:45:27 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
20/05/03 17:45:29 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/private/var/folders/1x/h0q3vtw17ddbys9bjcf41mtr0000gn/T/spark-5467a437-f3e2-4c23-9a15-9051aa89e222/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip -> hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000/user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/192.168.16.6:9866]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO DFSClient: Abandoning BP-1700972659-172.30.0.2-1588486994156:blk_1073741833_1009
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO DFSClient: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.16.6:9866,DS-6d0dcfb4-265a-4a8f-a86c-35fcc6e8ca70,DISK]
20/05/03 17:46:29 WARN DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000/user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007
20/05/03 17:46:29 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://foobars-mbp.box:4040
20/05/03 17:46:29 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/05/03 17:46:29 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/1x/h0q3vtw17ddbys9bjcf41mtr0000gn/T/spark-e77adcce-715f-43d1-a01e-d4141349ed13
20/05/03 17:46:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/1x/h0q3vtw17ddbys9bjcf41mtr0000gn/T/spark-5467a437-f3e2-4c23-9a15-9051aa89e222
```

Note the error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007/__spark_libs__8443981124167043301.zip could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.`

If I check `HDFS` while this is happening I see the `Spark` files have been uploaded:

```
hdfs@243579e354c0:/app$ hadoop fs -ls /user/foobar/.sparkStaging
WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete.
Found 2 items
drwx------   - foobar hadoop          0 2020-05-03 22:43 /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0006
drwx------   - foobar hadoop          0 2020-05-03 22:45 /user/foobar/.sparkStaging/application_1588537985407_0007
```

These are subsequently cleaned up when the job fails.

On the Spark worker UI I see the following: [image]. The workers are getting spawned and promptly exit (or are they killed?). There are no logs for `stdout` for an executor. However in `stderr` I see the following:

```
Spark Executor Command: "/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java" "-cp" "/app/config/:/app/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=51462" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@foobars-mbp.box:51462" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.16.10" "--cores" "8" "--app-id" "app-20200503204833-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.16.10:41839"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/05/03 20:48:34 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 84@ad4c05fe6b8a
20/05/03 20:48:34 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
20/05/03 20:48:34 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
20/05/03 20:48:34 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
20/05/03 20:48:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/05/03 20:48:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hdfs,foobar
20/05/03 20:48:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hdfs,foobar
20/05/03 20:48:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
20/05/03 20:48:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
20/05/03 20:48:35 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hdfs, foobar); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hdfs, foobar); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1748)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$3(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:277)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$1(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to foobars-mbp.box:51462
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:253)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: foobars-mbp.box
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:202)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:48)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:182)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:168)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:985)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:505)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:416)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:475)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

Additional config files that may be of importance:

*core-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*hdfs-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/app/data/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/app/data/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*spark-defaults.conf*

```
spark.master           yarn
spark.driver.memory    512m
spark.executor.memory  1g
spark.yarn.archive     hdfs:///user/foo/spark-libs.jar
```

*yarn-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>resource-manager:8032</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>resource-manager:8030</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>resource-manager:8031</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>resource-manager</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Why can't I submit a job via Yarn?

**----- UPDATE -----**

It seems like I can successfully submit a job *from* a docker container. For example:

`docker exec -it spark-master /bin/bash`

Then in the container:

`spark-submit --master yarn --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /app/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar 10`

Which eventually gives me:

`Pi is roughly 3.141983141983142`

This seems like it might be a networking issue when submitting outside of the container network. Is there anyway to debug this?

Comment: I think that what tells the resources of a work node is its configuration. Have you check `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` of your worker nodes?

Comment: Is your datanode listed in the namenodes Web UI?

Comment: @cronoik Yes, I see one active datanode in the namenode web UI.

Comment: Have you checked the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545524/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation)? Could it be a permission problem (docker vs user)?

Comment: @cronoik Yes I validated this. The docker containers are all using the same user and I've ensured this user has permissions to read/write in hdfs.

Comment: Looks like an issue with container localization, could you check your NodeManager logs? https://blog.cloudera.com/resource-localization-in-yarn-deep-dive/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was a networking issue. If you look closely at what was originally posted in the question you will see the following error in the log, one that I originally missed:

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/192.168.16.6:9866]
```

The IP address `192.168.16.6` is that of a Docker container, as it is seen inside of the Docker network. As I am submitting this from outside of the Docker containers, that IP will never be routable. So what's happening here:

1. I submit the job to the cluster.
2. I eventually get an IP address back for my (only) datanode.
3. I try and communicate with this datanode - which is the IP address of a Docker container, *in the docker network*.
4. This IP is not routable and eventually the request times out.

To fix this I initially setup my datanode container to use a specific `hostname` by adding the following to that container's definition in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
hostname: hadoop
```

Since I didn't have DNS setup, I added the following to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
10.0.2.2 hadoop
```

In this case `10.0.2.2` is my `localhost` *outside* of the Docker network - my actual host.

I then updated my Hadoop config so that the datanode will return a hostname, rather than an IP like so:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The subsequent `spark-submit` worked after this.

However an easier solution appears to be just adding `network_mode: host` to the requisite containers in my `docker-compose.yml`. Doing this made all of the above completely irrelevant. This is likely only ideal for a non-production environment - which in my case it is - so it works fine.